# I am getting a " 'GameObject[]' does not contain a definition for 'length' " error and I don't know where the issue is

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am coding a unity game for the first time for a game art class and have found some code that suits my purposes well.

The purpose was to end the game and transition to a different scene when all the enemies are gone (I will have a set number, although I am on the lookout for learning how to generate a random number of specific objects with specific properties).

However, I keep getting this error:

> Assets\code\GameWinner.cs(14,21): error CS1061: 'GameObject[]' does
> not contain a definition for 'length' and no accessible extension
> method 'length' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject[]'
> could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)

However, I can't find what the issue is in those lines and have no idea what I am missing because I have no idea how coding in c++ works, let alone unity c++. Worse, my teacher knows even less than I do, so he won't be able to help in this specific area (he never worked on the coding/scripting end of game creation)

So, I am wondering if any of you could spot what's going on and how to. Here is the code I am looking at. (let me know if any of you need to look at any of the other scripts I have).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameWinner : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public GameObject[] enemies;

    void Update()
    {
        enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy"); // Checks if enemies are available with tag "Enemy". Note that you should set this to your enemies in the inspector.
        if (enemies.length == 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2); // Load the scene with name "OtherSceneName"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

c# is case-sensitive.

```
if(enemies.Length == 0)
{
    ...
}
```

---

**Dissecting the error message:**

Programming is almost another word for reading everything, a lot and more, and as a never ending story.

`Assets\code\GameWinner.cs(14,21): error CS1061: 'GameObject[]' does not contain a definition for 'length' and no accessible extension method 'length' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

- Assets\code\GameWinner.cs

  The file the error occurs in:
- (14,21)

  The line and column number the error is in:
- error CS1061

  The error number, you can look these up at [learn.microsoft.com/.../compiler-messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/)
- 'GameObject[]'

  The type which is called when the error occurred
- 'length'

  The part which is the error
- (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

  Just a hint, it is in this case refering to 'length' as not known but this you could have read by all part of the error-message not mentioned in this list.

  i.e.: ... does not contain a definition for ... and no accessible extension method ... accepting a first argument of type ... could be found.

Comment: mg_pheonix You're sure about c++?

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. Failed to double check.