# How do I fix "does not contain a definition for" and "no accessible extension method" in unity after saving a C# script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was following this video on YouTube for creating a fps game, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJqP5EesxLk&t=614s, I got to the 9 min mark. When I saved my C# script and went on back to Unity there was two error messages and I don't know what they mean nor how fix them.
This is the first one:
Assets\Scripts\InputManager.cs(23,16): error CS1061: 'PlayerInput.OnFootActions' does not contain a definition for 'enable' and no accessible extension method 'enable' accepting a first argument of type 'PlayerInput.OnFootActions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
This is the second one:
Assets\Scripts\InputManager.cs(27,16): error CS1061: 'PlayerInput.OnFootActions' does not contain a definition for 'disable' and no accessible extension method 'disable' accepting a first argument of type 'PlayerInput.OnFootActions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image: This is my code following the video, I was noticing that some of the parts that were highlighted in the video wasn't highlighted for me]

Comment: The functions are `Enable` and `Disable` respectively.  C# is case sensitive.

Comment: Nice to have you onboard but please don't upload images with code. Copy and paste them using the code format. Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74309370/20378590

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.